# MDI parent background image

Tags: c#, image, background, parent, mdi

I have tried absolutely everything I could get my hand on, and it just won't work !
Has anyone ever solved this problem?

I can put my image in the back, but it works only if the form never tries to be resized (shrinking is OK, growing leaves empty grey space...)

Comment: You might get a better response if you post some of your code.  I suspect you'll have to add some code in your OnResize event handler.

Comment: @Guster_Q, @PK:

These solutions do not work, it was the first thing I tried to do ... Image appears correctly, but instantly you try to resize the form... well ... try it yourself ...
Image should ALWAYS be in the middle :(
For the PictureBox control, it appears above the Mdi child forms...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting MdiParent Background Image properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520373/setting-mdiparent-background-image-properly)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Long time ago, I've found there is an easy answer for this problem by using panel as a MDI container.

Comment: ...and yet you didn't indicate how you supposedly accomplished this? The Panel control does not have/support the ```IsMdiContainer``` property... 

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- Set Background image and change the
  BackgroundImageLayout property to
  Stretch (as suggested by
  [Guster_Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316310/mdi-parent-background-image/1316362#1316362))
- Set your image in a imagecontrol and
  set it docking property to fill

Answer (score 3):

I tried Form's resize event and it worked for me like this:

```
        private void Main_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.stockandinventorymanagement;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set RightToLeftLayout property to FALSE

Comment: This fixed the problem, but what if I must use `RightToLeftLayout`?

Comment: wow, works for me. it's ridiculous

Answer (score 2):

For others who arrived at this page via Google, I found the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19520556/1542024).

By putting this code in my form's `Initialize()` function, I was able to get a *properly* working MDI container background image, even for `WindowState` changes and form resizing:

```
// as this code occurs in the Form's "Initialize()" function, any references to
// "this." are to the Form instance itself (not the MDI control!)
MdiClient client = this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();
client.BackgroundImageLayout = this.BackgroundImageLayout;
client.Paint += ( s, e ) => 
    e.Graphics.DrawImage( this.BackgroundImage, (s as MdiClient).ClientRectangle );

//Set this to repaint when the size is changed
typeof( Control ).GetProperty( 
    "ResizeRedraw", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
).SetValue( client, true, null );

//set this to prevent flicker
typeof( Control ).GetProperty( 
    "DoubleBuffered", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
).SetValue( client, true, null );
```

For siimplicity, I made the MDI container use the Form's `BackgroundImage` (which it hides anyway) and `BackgroundImageLayout` properties so that I could easily set/modify those settings using the Form's own properties in Designer and have those settings reflected in the designer-inaccessible MDI container automatically. This also meant that I didn't have to worry about managing garbage collection of the image and could get rid of the `Using {}` code found in the original snippet (which actually caused errors because the image itself was disposed by the Using block and then crashed the form as soon as it attempted to display the now-missing image).

Answer (score 0):

Change the BackgroundImageLayout property to Stretch.  This will stretch your image to always fill the backgound space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

IMPORTANT: The property 'BackgroundImageLayout' of the form must be equal to the code

```
        Dim ctl As Control

        For Each ctl In Me.Controls

            If TypeOf ctl Is MdiClient Then
                ctl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                ctl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
                ctl.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Image.png")
            End If

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for idea !!!!
it's too easy just change background of panel and put this below code 
c#:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Show();
```

this for vb.net

```
    Dim frm  = New Form2
    frm .TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(frm )
    frm .Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control ctrlControl in this.Controls)
  {
    if (ctrlControl is MdiClient)
    {
      BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Mbck;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to add the background image to the instance of the object as opposed to the static definition of the object.

With that in mind what I did is to:

1. Drop a panel onto the mid form
2. Make it dock the whole form...not required
3. Add a picture box to the panel
4. In the load procedure of the mid form,
   Add this code:

```cs
Me.picturebox1.image = image.fromfile("c:\filename.jpg")
Me.picturebox1.show()
```

And it worked.

May even make the code more sleek by not using the picture box and the panel and referencing the image not from disk but from a resource in the project!

Comment: Typo ...mid form is MDI form