# MDI child form borders get painted over MDI parent when background image is set

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was trying to set the background image of the MDI parent form and used the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63972688/8494981 to set it.

```
private void SetMdiBackgroundImage()
{
    //Get the MdiClient itself
    MdiClient client = this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();

    //Set the image layout of client to be the image layout of the form
    client.BackgroundImageLayout = this.BackgroundImageLayout;

    //Draw the image manually
    client.Paint += (s, e) =>
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, (s as MdiClient).ClientRectangle);

    //Set this to repaint when the size is changed
    typeof(Control).GetProperty(
         "ResizeRedraw",
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
        ).SetValue(client, true, null);

    //set this to prevent flicker
    typeof(Control).GetProperty(
         "DoubleBuffered",
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
        ).SetValue(client, true, null);
}
```

but there is an issue when a child form is open and gets dragged across the form like below:
[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes - manually invalidate the areas of your parent form that the child is being dragged over.

Comment: Remove the event handler: `client.Paint += (s, e) => ...`, it's useless. And `client.GetType().GetProperty(...)`. Just assign a BackgroundiImage to the MDIForm, it's set to the MdiClient control. Call that method from the MDIForm Constructor. -- Note that ScrollBars are added to the MDIForm: the image will get quite *jumpy* if you drag a child Form outside the MDI bounds. MDI Forms rarely use background images (a small logo, maybe). MDI itself is quite obsolete stuff.

Comment: @Jimi Removing the event handler for paint will cause the background image to not appear in the MDI form

Comment: @IanKemp. This solves the issue, but I have to subscribe to the event of every child form

Comment: Of course it *appears*. It's already there, if you have set the BackgroundImage of your MDI Form. Maybe you mean that it doesn't appear in the Designer (fortunately). You just need to double-buffer MdiClient. `ResizeDraw` does the rest. No need for handlers. -- Remember to call `SetMdiBackgroundImage()` from the MDI Form Constructor. If you haven't set a BackgroundImage, you can set it there, too.

Comment: @Jimi It seems you misunderstood me. The image doesn't show up when the event handler is removed, not that it still shows

Comment: If you have set the BackgroundImage of your MDIForm (have you?) then it shows up in any case (at run-time, of course). Double-buffering the MdiClient is useful because it prevents *tearing* (the effect that is visible when you resize the MDI Form). Works if couple with `ResizeRedraw`. The event handler has no use because the Image is already there: when you set the BackgroundImage of MDI Form, it's set automatically to the MdiClient Control. -- Also, I've already tested it, just to make sure, since you said otherwise. -- Specify the .Net version in use. Did you add it to the Form Constructor?

Comment: @Jimi. Yes I have set the background image. I use .Net framework 4.8

Comment: Well, then it's same version I tested it with. -- You still haven't said when you're calling that method. -- You must see the background image in any case.: with that code, without it or using half of it. Otherwise, a piece is missing.

Comment: @Jimi Found the issue. Somehow, setting the form to "Right To Left" causes the photo to not show up

Comment: Ahh, `RightToLeft` + `RightToLeftLayout`, the former alone won't cause it. The BackgroundLayoutEngine doesn't work with `RightToLeftLayout`. Other stuff doesn't either (e.g., TransparencyKey). I didn't notice from the image you're showing in the OP. Yes, you have to paint it and handle a BufferedGraphics object manually. The Graphics of the image drawn in the background is not buffered.